# How to declare openlayers map object globally

Tags: javascript, npm, openlayers, package.json, openlayers-6

I have generated a map using ol 6. I have added an osm layer. Now I want to add a vector , which is coded in another javascript file. I want to use the same 'map' object . I tried to declare globally but its not working. My code is

**map.js**

```
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
var map;

map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      title: 'OSM',
      source: new OSM(),
      opacity: 0.5,
    })
  ]
  });
```

**analysis.js**

```
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';

var vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
          features: [new Feature({
              geometry: new Point([571544.3902,1310700.2529]),
              featureProjection: "EPSG:32643",
              name: 'Somewhere near Nottingham',
         })],
         crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        }),

      style: new Style({
        image: new Icon({
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png'
        })
          })
      })
map.addLayer(vector ); //this results in 'map' undefined error.
```

I used npm to install ol. & my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "gis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "map*.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel map.js",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . map*.js"
  },
  "author": "user123",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "^6.4.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you want to use that, but why not orchestrate the building of the map in the file that uses it in the end? What you are trying to do does not seem too well-thought-out to me. But you could export the map from your map.js and then import it in analysis.js if you really want to.

Comment: I want to add a lots(more than 10 I think) of analysis in this map, like heatmap, cluster,earthquake etc. which I want to keep in separate files for easiness.

Comment: which should not be a problem if you structure your code neatly. Check my answer @user123

Answer (score 2):

Export map object in your map.js then import it in analysis.js:

**map.js**

```
const map = new Map (...)

export default map
```

**analysis.js**

```
import map from './map.js'
(...)
map.addLayer (vector);
```

Comment: `map.addLayer (vector);` is getting error. ***Uncaught TypeError: s.default is undefined***. But there is no `s` variable

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to orchestrate the building of the map in something like a "main

```
// map.js

import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';

// export as "factory" function 
export const getMap = () => new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            title: 'OSM',
            source: new OSM(),
            opacity: 0.5,
        })
    ]
});
```

```
// analysis.js

import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';

// export as "factory" function 
export const getVectorLayer = () => new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
        features: [new Feature({
            geometry: new Point([571544.3902, 1310700.2529]),
            featureProjection: "EPSG:32643",
            name: 'Somewhere near Nottingham',
        })],
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    }),

    style: new Style({
        image: new Icon({
            src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png'
        })
    })
});
```

```
// main.js

import { getMap } from 'map';
import { getVectorLayer } from 'analysis';

const map = getMap();
const vector = getVectorLayer();

map.addLayer(vector);
```

If you don't want to do that, just import the map in the `analysis.js` instead of `main.js` and call the function there.

Comment: I got error ***Uncaught TypeError: n.getMap is not a function*** at getMap(). I changed the import line to ***import { getMap } from './map';***

Comment: What is `n`?? @user123

Comment: there is no 'n'..its showing error at line ***const map = getMap();*** . Now showing ***Uncaught TypeError: s.getMap is not a function***

Comment: Maybe try importing it using `require()`. Hard to guess what's wrong if I don't see the whole setup. @user123